# javascript: I need to get an object key from the function argument

Tags: javascript, function, object

vm.contributorAmountPerYear[index-1] gets me an object, and I want its key to be the year argument of the function.

```
    function getAgriAmount(year,amount,index) {
          if (typeof amount !== "number" ) {
            amount = parseInt(amount ||0);
          };
          var argiYearlyLocalCost = vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost;
           console.log(vm.contributorAmountPerYear[index-1].year);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any javascript object, you should keep in mind that if you use `.` dot notation, you cannot access the properties for keys that come from a variable and are determined at runtime. Use square bracket notation [] for such a case. This should work:

```
vm.contributorAmountPerYear[index-1][year];
```

Dot notation should be used when you already know the key:

```
var cuteJavaScriptObject = {
    animal : 'cat'
}

var myVar = 'animal';

console.log(cuteJavaScriptObject.animal); // OK

console.log(cuteJavaScriptObject.myVar); // Wrong !!

console.log(cuteJavaScriptObject[myVar]); // Now OK
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vm.contributorAmountPerYear[index-1][year]
```